# Getting Android Emulator to work with iPhone Hotspot

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, emulation

My home Internet is down and I need to run some tests on my Android emulator. My MacBook Pro is connected to the Internet via my iPhone Hotspot using bluetooth. Connection is ok - not super fast. The Android emulator is running on my MacBook Pro. Unfortunately emulator cannot connect to Internet. Any tips on how I can get the emulator to detect the internet connection?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

This method worked on my Macbook Pro 2019. I haven't tested it on windows though.

**On Windows**

Open Network and Sharing Center and click on current Connection
Click on Properties
Double Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
Set the Preferred and Alternate DNS servers as:

*8.8.8.8*

*8.8.4.4*

**On Mac**

Go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced... > DNS
Delete whatever entries you have there and add these two entries:

*8.8.8.8*

*8.8.4.4*

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/cpp/android+emulator+internet+not+working+in+iphone+hotspot

Comment: this actually worked. should be marked as correct answer

Comment: It worked for me also but I had to do extra things. 1) I think my service provider blocks this DNS, so I had to enable VPN first. Then the Google DNS was working. 2) I had to wipe the data from the android emulator and cold boot it. Then finally the internet was working in the emulator.